# Fetch data from a given website

Tags: asp.net

I want to create a web service in ASP.NET that fetches data from a website every hour or so (the storing part I got it covered).  [In this example](http://www.metacritic.com/video/titles/12rounds), metacritic.com, how can I get the Users score of a movie at any given time interval?

What I know is, I would have to get the source of the website and then find the html element that contains the data I want (by name in the best of the cases) but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks in advance for any help!

[alt text http://img354.imageshack.us/img354/9351/200907030136.png](http://img354.imageshack.us/img354/9351/200907030136.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the HTTP request side of things, `WebClient` is probably the easiest.

For a simple, blocking HTTP request, do this:

```
string page = (new WebClient()).DownloadString("http://foo.bar/page");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can send an http request and parse the output html to retrieve the value. Otherwise you can try to find out, if MetaCritic has a webservice itself, what I think is reasonable because Steam includes MetaCritic scores too.

Best Regards
Oliver Hanappi

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a HTTP request to the website and then parse the HTML source by identifying unique flags around the variable score.

Answer (score 1):

Use the HttpWebRequest class to open the site, then search the returned Response for the specific HTML element , probably using something like

`responsestring.IndexOf("class=\"scoreelemementclass\"")`