# Fetch a snippet of string value from any website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, httpwebrequest, data-mining

I'm trying to create a rails app that fetches album scores from PitchforkMedia.com
For example, I want to grab the [score 8.0 from this album](http://www.pitchforkmedia.com/reviews/albums/15928-dj-kicks/?utm_campaign=most-read-week&utm_medium=related&utm_source=pitchfork) as shown below in the image.

In my brief research, I came across a similar question [asked from asp.net point of view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078428/fetch-data-from-a-given-website).

Generally, the answers suggested

1. using http request
2. parse the HTML source
3. identifying unique flags around the variable score

Some answers came with use of built in asp.net functions.

Are there equivalent functions available in Ruby or Ruby on Rails?
Or can someone suggest some other way doing what I want to do?

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you.

**Edit 1: This is completely for personal use and education. Assume that there is no legal ramification for data mining from websites.**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Mechanize to scrape the content that you are interested in. Ryan Bates has a [great screencast on how to use Mechanize](http://railscasts.com/episodes/191-mechanize).

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you're reading the site's terms of use before you start screen-scraping data, especially if it's not for personal use.

This is a portion of Pitchfork's terms of use, and most other sites have something similar.

"Any reproduction, copying or redistribution of the Materials or design elements of the Website for any purpose are strictly prohibited without the express written consent of Pitchfork or its owner if Pitchfork is not the owner."

Screen scraping definitely falls in this category.

Comment: This is completely for personal use and education. It doesn't even have to be Pitchfork Score. If getting score from Pitchfork bothers you, say I want to grab date of birth of Churchill from Wikipedia page instead.